# how to enable HTTP/2

Tags: nginx, https, tls1.2

I am new to nginx. I had HTTP2 enabled on my server but my server is still making several tcp connections, 
as per http2 norms only one tcp connection should be made. I have followed the process to enabled HTTP/2 from https://www.bjornjohansen.no/enable-http2-on-nginx

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Should just be a 'listen 443 ssl http2'. There is a chrome plugin that indicate if http2 is working. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en

Comment: @FaisalMemon: thnak you for response, I have same.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL are you using? https://www.nginx.com/blog/supporting-http2-google-chrome-users/